# React main entry point

Tags: reactjs, architecture, program-entry-point, entry-point

I don't understand the structure of most boilerplates out there. I always see 2 files named "index" (one js file and an other html file). I want to understand how the main entry point works. I often see web pack for this job but my main concern is, why do am I using an index.html file when I can (I guess) do all my work in js file?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well I structure my React apps like this:

**index.js** - calls ReactDOM.render() on **app.jsx**, which is the root React component.

**bundle.js** - This file is where index.js and all the JSX components are merged after being compiled into regular JavaScript using Webpack (hence bundle).

**index.html** - bundle.js is imported into the body of this html file through script tag, this is the entry point.

Comment: okay, thanks!  I got you

Comment: Thank you! I've misunderstood some parts because I skipped the setup part of the tutorial. I had a tool generate the project for me without an index.js so there lies my problem